# Restart Service as soon as wifi is available

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I have got a little service that is going to download a file every day at 6am. This works totally fine (I solved this with the AlarmManager), but if there is no internet connection at 6am I would like to restart this service as soon as internet connection is available. The service is a started one and never bound.

I already invoke a method called "onNoInternetConnection" within my service whenever there is no internet connection available, so this is already implemented correctly and works fine, but as I am new to android I am a little lost in the issue about how to restart my service as soon as internet connection is available.

I thought about implementing a broadcast receiver listening for a connectivity change, but I run into different problems there like when exactly to register or unregister the receiver and how to avoid that the receiver will not start the service before 6am (this is important)...

Is this the right approach to achieve this and if yes, when exactly and how can I register my broadcast receiver? If not: Do you have other approaches to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance ! Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to register the receiver dynamically. Just do it in your `Manifest`

```
<receiver android:name=".ConnectivityChangeReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Then check internet connection in `onReceive` method:

```
public class ConnectivityChangeReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //if connected to the internet then start service if not the do nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer! Yes, but if I do it this way, how do I prevent that my service starts over and over again every time I get internet connection? This receiver would start itself whenever The connectivity changes, but I only would like to run the service, if it is past 6am and if there was no internet connection after 6am. It shall run once more then, as soon as internet is available and never again afterwards.

Comment: In other words: I want to start my service the very first time internet connection is available after 6am and never again that day.

Comment: @Pat You can't create more than one instance of `Service`. If a service already started then method `onStart` of the running `Service` will be only called.

Comment: What I mean is whenever the service has done it's job it will stop itself and gets destroyed. If it has done its job successfully there is no need to start the service again.

Comment: @Pat so save somewhere(for instance in `SharedPreference`) that "job was done at <time>". And check saved time in the receiver.

Comment: this sounds as if it would work, but it is still not the very best solution, since I would always have to check if the service has already done its job and if it is already after 6am (and some other things). And the app would need to check this every time the connectivity changes. And is it that common to store such information in the sharedPreferences? I thought these would only be used for user preferences. Nevertheless if there are no other solutions, I will try this out tomorrow morning. Thank you ! +1

Comment: @Pat `SharedPreferences` is just the most easy way to store simple data.